# Split on Regex Not At Beginning of Line

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking to split a string on spaces but not if those spaces are at the beginning of the line, here's what I have so far:

```js
alert(JSON.stringify(
  '  this   is   a  test'.split(/(?!^\s+)\s+/)
))
```

but that only works if there's only one space in the beginning or the string.

I know that javascript doesn't support lookbehinds, is there anyway to do this without a hack like reversing the string?

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript this should work:

```
'   this   is   a  test'.split(/(^\s+\S+)|\s+/).filter(Boolean)
//=> ["   this", "is", "a", "test"]
```

i.e. group all the desired text on LHS of alternation and keep split pattern on RHS of pipe.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(JSON.stringify(
  '  this   is   a  test'.trim().split(/(?!^\s+)\s+/)
))
```

Comment: I think that OP and everybody else thought on `trim`, but the challenge is to do it in one regex, I think.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Correct, I'd rather not use `trim()`